# Bokeh - Adding a new plot on click of a button

Tags: bokeh

I am using bokeh to plot some graphs. I will be using bokeh serve to serve a python notebook. My use case is as follows:

The page will load with a text box and button. Based on the data that is entered into the text box , I need to show different graphs on button click.

What is the best way to go about it. I have tried adding the plot to the current doc and such. but none of them seem to be working.

I am using bokeh 0.11.1

Comment: Did you find anything on this?